# How to pass multiple variable from ui.r to server.r in shiny app in a reactive manner

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

ui.r
this is mainly for the data analysis for the sales per day of a store

```
   shinyUI(fluidPage(
          titlePanel("Sales Analysis"),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              helpText("Create line graph for  
                       Sale."),
              selectInput(multiple='TRUE' ,"var", 
                          label = "Choose a year to display",
                          choices = c(Result),
                          selected = "Result[1]",
           selectInput( "var2", 
            label1 = "Choose a month to display",
            choices1 = c(Result2),
            selected1 = "Result2[1]")),
            mainPanel(
              plotOutput("lineplot"),
              print(Result),
              print(Result1)
            )
          )
        ))
```

server.r

this is mainly for the data analysis for the sales per day of a store
using shiny web app  ,so whats I am trying to is have multiple drop down box in ui.r,want to select one drop down  based on that the other drop down to be selected then these selected drop down variable passed to server.r where it should be passed in queries to be reactive way .

```
library(shiny)library for shiny web browser
library(DBI) database package
library(rJava)for connection basic package
library(RJDBC) 
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(PKI)
library(RCurl)
library(rsconnect)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$lineplot <- renderPlot({ 

    jcc = JDBC("","")
    conn = dbConnect(jcc,"//",user="",
                     password="")
    Result<-dbGetQuery(conn,statement = paste("select sale_dt,count(trd) as Bill from retail_str_sales_master where year(sale_date)=",input$var," group by sale_date"))
    Result$SALE_DATE<-as.Date(Result$SALE_Dt)
    #Result1<-dbGetQuery(conn,statement = paste("select sale_dt,count(trd) as Bill from retail_str_sales_master where to_char(to_date(month(sale_date),'MM'),'Month')=",input$var,"  group by sale_date"))

  draw the line Graph with the specified number of bins using Sale date and Total no Of Bills
    ggplot(Result,aes(x=SALE_DATE,y=BILL))+geom_line()+geom_point()+scale_x_date(date_breaks ="2 day", date_labels=("%d-%m-%y"))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks =seq (0,max(Result$BILL),200))+ylab("Total No Of Bills")+xlab("sale date")+theme_bw()+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5,hjust = 0.5))


  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `renderUI()`. Here is an example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: The problem is I have used query to get the value in UI part .for single year value the graph is coming out good.But as I need to select month based on year and then passed the value to server in the query, this is where the thing is not working I am not able to pass two variables in where condition in the query to make the graph dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Fix indentation errors and check if the problem persists.

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sales Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create line graph for  
                       Sale."),
      selectInput(multiple='TRUE' ,"var", 
                  label = "Choose a year to display",
                  choices = c(Result),
                  selected = Result[1]),
      selectInput( "var2", 
                   label1 = "Choose a month to display",
                   choices1 = c(Result2),
                   selected1 = Result2[1])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("lineplot"),
      print(Result),
      print(Result1)
    )
  )
))
```